# Getting the value of correlation Id from Serilog programatically

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, serilog

I am using Serilog for logging in my Web API project, with the web classic nuget package installed I am simply able to log a unique GUID value per request.
From my Logger is there anyway to access that value? I know that any time I am writing to a file it should be written to it, but I want to read it from the logger context, is there anyway of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no method that is supported/straightforward (there may be some hacks, you'd need to read the source for the *SerilogWeb.Classic* package to figure this out however).

If you add an `ILogEventEnricher` to the pipeline, it can inspect `LogEvent`s emitted during the request and retrieve the `HttpRequestId` at that point - though I'm unsure if this is useful in your scenario.